# Grouping connected data

Tags: oracle, grouping

I have a table in Oracle 11 with 2 columns. Each row contains IDs which belong together.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( CaseId1, CaseID2 ) AS
  SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'H', 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Z', 'X' FROM DUAL Union ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'X' FROM DUAL Union ALL
  SELECT 'X', 'A' FROM DUAL Union ALL
```

E.g.

> Row 1: A > B; Row 2: B > C; Row 3: C > D
>
> Row 1-3 belong together, as they are connected.

So I want to have in column 3 an ID for this groupd, e.g. 1.

Expected Output:

```
CaseId1 CaseId2 GroupId
------- ------- -------
A       B       1
B       C       1
C       D       1
A       X       1
X       A       1
H       I       1
I       X       1
Z       X       1
E       F       2
F       G       2
```

I know that there is a built in function in Oracle but I do not know how to convert it so that it fits what I need.

```
SELECT     ENAME
FROM       EMP
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO = MGR
START WITH ENAME = 'JONES';
```

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_hierarchical_queries.htm

Comment: Do you really have `'Z', 'X'` in the last row or is this a typo and they should be the other way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` to get a unique identifier from the top-level of the hierarchy to use as the id of the group:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp ( empno, ename, mgr ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'A', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'D', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'E', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'F', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'G', 5 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT e.*,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( empno ) AS top_level_mgr
FROM   emp e
START WITH mgr IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> EMPNO | ENAME |  MGR | TOP_LEVEL_MGR
> ----: | :---- | ---: | ------------:
>     1 | A     | null |             1
>     2 | B     |    1 |             1
>     3 | C     |    2 |             1
>     4 | D     | null |             4
>     5 | E     |    4 |             4
>     6 | F     |    5 |             4
>     7 | G     |    5 |             4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e752eb5ce89869d324baca09045b490)*

---

**Update**

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( CaseId1, CaseID2 ) AS
  SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'H', 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Z', 'X' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT( CaseId1 ) ) AS group_id
FROM   table_name t
START WITH NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name x
  WHERE  x.ROWID != t.ROWID
  AND    x.caseId2 IN ( t.CaseId1, t.CaseId2 )
)
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
     PRIOR ROWID != ROWID
AND  PRIOR CaseId2 IN ( CaseId1, CaseId2 )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> CASEID1 | CASEID2 | GROUP_ID
> :------ | :------ | -------:
> A       | B       |        1
> B       | C       |        1
> C       | D       |        1
> E       | F       |        2
> F       | G       |        2
> H       | I       |        3
> I       | X       |        3
> Z       | X       |        3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9a007eb408077cd2f3c1b9f16336a32)*

---

**Update 2**:

If you can connect by either `CaseId1` or `CaseId2` to either `CaseId1` or `CaseId2` then you can use:

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT CaseId1,
       CaseId2,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY MIN( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ROWID ) ) ) AS group_id
FROM   table_name t
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
     PRIOR ROWID != ROWID
AND  (  PRIOR CaseId2 IN ( CaseId1, CaseId2 )
     OR PRIOR CaseId1 IN ( CaseId1, CaseId2 ) )
GROUP BY
       CaseId1,
       CaseId2
```

*(I had to get rid of the `START WITH` as there was no way to determine which rows to start from as you could now traverse the hierarchy in either direction [or from the middle outwards]; instead the query will try to generate the hierarchy from every start point and will find the minimal root [as determined by the `ROWID` pseudo-column] that reaches each row and uses this to identify the groups.)*

**Output**:

> ```
> CASEID1 | CASEID2 | GROUP_ID
> :------ | :------ | -------:
> B       | C       |        1
> H       | I       |        1
> I       | X       |        1
> A       | B       |        1
> A       | X       |        1
> C       | D       |        1
> Z       | X       |        1
> E       | F       |        2
> F       | G       |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=38b95190ffb1e03d0a5229732ed45867)*

---

**Update 3**:

Lets give the query somewhere to start with to reduce the number of duplicates the hierarchical query is going to generate .... and store the data in a table as it goes. If you need to you can include a `COMMIT` at each iteration.

PL/SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ( group_id NUMBER(8,0) );

CREATE SEQUENCE group_id_seq;

DECLARE
  r_id   ROWID;
  grp_id NUMBER(8,0);
BEGIN
  LOOP
    SELECT ROWID
    INTO   r_id
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  group_id IS NULL
    AND    ROWNUM = 1;

    grp_id := group_id_seq.NEXTVAL;

    UPDATE table_name dst
    SET group_id = grp_id
    WHERE  ROWID IN (
      SELECT ROWID
      FROM   table_name
      START WITH ROWID = r_id
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
           PRIOR ROWID != ROWID
      AND  (  PRIOR CaseId2 IN ( CaseId1, CaseId2 )
           OR PRIOR CaseId1 IN ( CaseId1, CaseId2 ) )
    );

    /* COMMIT */ -- Optional if you want it to save repeatedly but it will be slower.    
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CASEID1 | CASEID2 | GROUP_ID
> :------ | :------ | -------:
> A       | B       |        1
> B       | C       |        1
> C       | D       |        1
> E       | F       |        2
> F       | G       |        2
> H       | I       |        1
> I       | X       |        1
> Z       | X       |        1
> A       | X       |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bb15880a6b2c07f5aeee165b91905844)*

---

**Update 4**:

A non-hierarchical version of update 3 (its adding a column to persist the group ids and then, starting each group with a row where the group id is unset, performs a breadth-first search updating the group ids as they are reached):

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ( group_id NUMBER(8,0) );

CREATE SEQUENCE group_id_seq;

DECLARE
  TYPE rowid_table IS TABLE OF ROWID;
  r_ids  rowid_table;
  grp_id table_name.group_id%TYPE;

BEGIN
  LOOP
    SELECT ROWID
    BULK COLLECT INTO r_ids
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  group_id IS NULL
    AND    ROWNUM = 1
    FOR UPDATE;

    EXIT WHEN r_ids.COUNT = 0;

    grp_id := group_id_seq.NEXTVAL;

    WHILE r_ids.COUNT > 0 LOOP
      FORALL i IN 1 .. r_ids.COUNT 
        UPDATE table_name
        SET    group_id = grp_id
        WHERE  ROWID = r_ids(i);

      SELECT ROWID
      BULK COLLECT INTO r_ids
      FROM   table_name t
      WHERE  group_id IS NULL
      AND    EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM   table_name x
        WHERE  (  t.CaseId2 IN ( x.CaseId1, x.CaseId2 )
               OR t.CaseId1 IN ( x.CaseId1, x.CaseId2 ) )
        AND    group_id = grp_id
      )
      FOR UPDATE;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

> ```
> CASEID1 | CASEID2 | GROUP_ID
> :------ | :------ | -------:
> A       | B       |        1
> B       | C       |        1
> C       | D       |        1
> E       | F       |        2
> F       | G       |        2
> H       | I       |        1
> I       | X       |        1
> Z       | X       |        1
> A       | X       |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8693d97bfe276f2935b63ad3e9fdfd6e)*

Comment: thx, but i don't have the MGR column. I only have 2 columns: Case1 and Case2. The MGR is from another query which I wanted to share. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @zafiros You do have a `MGR` column in the code you posted in the question. Its referenced in the `CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO = MGR` line. How are we meant to answer your question if you give us the wrong information? If you want an answer relevant for your situation then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57784389/edit) your question to make it relevant for your situation with a complete [MRE] including DDL for your table and example data and what you expect your output to be.

Comment: The MGR is from another query which I wanted to share. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @zafiros Please do not paste data into comments as it is not readable and comments can be deleted or not read by all users. Instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57784389/edit) your question.

Comment: ok. I added a picture into the original question. I hope this makes it now clearer what  I need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am testing it currently... My table has around 60'000 records, the query is already running 20min. I hope this is normal...

Comment: @MT0, Is there any way to do more than 1 upvote on SO?

Comment: @MT0: Unfortunately, the grouping is not yet correct. It only groups the direct connection, e.g. A with B and A with C. But the connection of B with other cases is not grouped.

My table has 60'000 records and the query returns only 12'000 records.

Comment: @zafiros Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57784389/edit) your question with some sample data that illustrates the problem as just saying "its not yet correct" is not constructive when the answer gives the expected answer for the data you've given.

Comment: @MT0: I added 1 more line into your create statement (A, X). This will show you that this connection gets not added to the groupID 1. :-(

Comment: @MT0: Added also another line (X,A) as they might also be connected the other way round.

Comment: @MT0: I run the code using a temp table with only 50 records, the result looks good so far. But when I use the original table with 60'000 records, it does not return a result. The query is running now for 90mins... the performance does not play a role, i am fine if i get it in 12h, at least i get it:-). I will let you know! But hey, your help is extremely appreciated: thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: @MT0: The query stopped working, I had to restart Oracle. I will run it now again, if you have an idea how to improve it then  I am happy to know it.

Comment: @zafiros updated with PL/SQL in an attempt to make it more performant.

Comment: @MT0: Thanks! Unfortunately, the query gets not fully executed. It processes approx. 10 records only, then it gets stuck and does not update anymore.

Comment: @zafiros Updated with a non-hierarchical version. If that doesn't work then I'm not sure that I can help any more as your problem is with performance on a large data-set and that is something I cannot test. However, if you can generate a [MRE] showing how one of the queries gets stuck after only 10 rows then I might be able to debug that - but my guess is that it gets stuck due to the size of the data-set and generating too many rows and a small set of rows won't replicate that issue.

Comment: You may also be able to speed it up with indexes on your columns.